# Checking if email is already taken in database

Tags: php, database

```
else if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phash = sha1(sha1($pass."salt")."salt");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, email) VALUES ('', '$user', '$phash', '$email');";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

How do I add an email checker here so that no one can have the same email while signing up

Comment: why not select from database? Also .. and more importantly .. you're open to SQL injection ..

Comment: Please read and learn about the benefits of using the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" to prevent potential sql injection vulnerabilities...

Comment: Add a `UNIQUE` index to the email column... I guarantee you won't have any duplicates then.

Answer (score 0):

you can select the email from your records to see if someone had taken this email or add unique index to email column to make sure the email field is unique. By the way,using prepared statement is better.

Comment: Thanks. Did not think of that

Answer (score 0):

As above said,you should use prepared statement,but with mysqli_real_escape_string and htmlspecialchars also good way to prevent sql injection,about your answer,you have to select your table to see if there is any exist email like below :

```
    if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phash = sha1(sha1($pass."salt")."salt");
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '{$mail}'");
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
    {
    echo "Email exist";
    }else
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES ('$user', '$phash', '$email')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 }   
}
```

And it's better to wrap your column name with this "`",one more thing,if your id is auto increment, omit the id column, you don't need to add the id column in your INSERT query.